# value getLogger is not a member of object System.Logger

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I have imported the import 'java.lang.System.Logger.Level' and 'import java.lang.System.Logger' library in intellij editor but can't get rid of this error.Same program is running fine in eclipse ide.

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that this works in Eclipse, given that those methods don't exist indeed on `java.lava.System.Logger`: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.Logger.html Are you sure you're not trying to import an SLF4J logger instead and importing the wrong classes?